# c++ reading from file

Tags: c++, getline

I am trying to write a program that will read integers from file and display them along with a running average. I have written code to do this and it  works when the file I am reading from is in the format of:

```
5 6 7 8 9
2 3 4 1 2 
4 5 7 8 9 
2 5 6 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5
```

I am trying to make the same program read (and display the int and average as before) from a file containing:

```
3 4 5

3

5

7 8 9
```

but it doesn't display as I want it any help would be appreciated.
here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    double y = 0, x = 0, value1 = 0;
    string myFileName, myString;
    cout << "please enter the name of the file you wish to open" << "\n";
    cin >> myFileName;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(myFileName.c_str());

    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        double currentAv;

        while (getline(inFile, myString, (' ')))
        {
            y = y + 1;
            value1 = atof(myString.c_str());
            currentAv = (value1 + x) / y;
            cout << myString << "," << currentAv << endl;
            x = value1 + x;
        }
    }

    inFile.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

the output I get when I enter the first file to be opened is:
     5,5
     6,6.5
     7,6
     .......

I would like the second file when entered to display the same ie the integer and its running average but I get:

```
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
,3
```

Comment: "but it doesn't display as I want it" then what is it doing? have you stepped through with a debugger to understand why its doing this?

Comment: My thoughts detector is offline for maintenance, Captain, so I have trouble identifying how you want the display to be :)

Comment: Could you possibly be any more vague? Please **edit** your post and include the output you expect _and_ the output you receive.

Comment: sorry when I run the first file I get the number 5 then the average 5 then  the number 6 and the average 6.5. I want it to read the second file in the same way but it outputs 3 4 5 6 7 on a newline each followed by the average of 3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify this portion of your code...

```
        double currentAv;

        while (inFile >> value1)
        {
            y = y + 1;
            currentAv = (value1 + x) / y;
            cout << value1 << "," << currentAv << endl;
            x = value1 + x;
        }
```

Comment: that works but only for the second file I need it to work with both files :(

Comment: what is the correct output for 1st file?

Comment: I need it to display all integers ,1 per line followed by a ','then then the running average for any size of .txt file which may include blank lines or single integers on lines.

Comment: 5,5;
6,5.5;
7,6;
8,6.5;
9,7;
. . . this should be the output sequence for 1st file

Comment: Above solution gives that result..

Comment: sorry your right I must have tried wrong file, doh. Thank you so much for your help :D